# 2-variable limit problem

Tags: calculus, limits

I can't solve some limits, and can't find resources online on how to solve this.

I can use double limits (replace `X` and `Y` at the same time) or sucessive limits, replacing one each variable separately.

If the limit doesn't exist, I have to show why.

Could someone help me out? Thank you very much!

Problems:

$$\lim_{x\to 0,y\to 0} \frac{3x - 2y}{2x + 3y}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0,y\to 0} ((x ^ 2 + 2y)  \sin (\frac{1}{xy}))$$

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, I am teaching myself limits so it is hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Mathematica, I find it very useful to look at the graph. Although this problem is very solvable on paper as well.

First problem:

Direct substitution won't work, because it's indeterminate. One method is to let t=x,t=y and find the limit of a single variable, t. This makes the limit (t)/(5t) = 1/5. This is effectively approaching the limit along the line x=y.

To try a different line, let t=-x,t=y (the line y=-x). From this approach, the limit is (-5t)/(t) = -5. Since these values are different, the function approaches a different value from different directions, and the limit does not exist. This method will only work to prove a limit's non-existence. You cannot prove that a limit exists with this methods, only disprove it.

Second Problem:

You can basically use direct substitution, just keep in mind that the sin(anything) must be within [-1,1]. As the values approach zero, the limit's upper and lower bounds also go to zero, so you can effectively use the squeeze/sandwich theorem, and then (0)*(-1) <= answer <= (0)*(1) and 0 <= answer <= 0

Comment: The second problem isn't that simple. Sin of infinite isn't defined.

Comment: There is no unanimity of definition in the second problem. The answer depends on the precise definition that is being used in your course.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I was unaware. I just know that the limit is infinitely close to zero, so for Pacha's class zero should probably be fine, right? Because the limit goes to (0)*(sin(undefined)) so (0)*(-1) <= answer <= (0)*(1)

Comment: If we will decide that the limit exists, then that limit will be simply $0$. The issue is that evvery deleted neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ contains points at which the function is not defined, such as $(0,\epsilon)$, for arbitrarily small non-zero $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Platatat There is no such thing as "the limit is infinitely close to zero". The limit is zero or it isn't (unless you are talking about surreal or hyperreal numbers).

Comment: But if the function is bounded above and below by functions whose limits are zero, then isn't the limit of the function zero? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem

Comment: Isn't the first problem solved easiest by calculating a limit for $y\to 0$ with $x=0$, then a limit for $x\to 0$ with $y=0$...?

Answer (score 0):

First limit does not exist, because if we consider 2 different sequences $(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ and $(\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n})$ which both converges to (0,0), then we have
$$\frac{3 \frac{1}{n} - 2\frac{1}{n}}{2\frac{1}{n} + 3\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{1}{5}$$
$$\frac{3 \frac{1}{n} - 2\frac{2}{n}}{2\frac{1}{n} + 3\frac{2}{n}} = -\frac{1}{8}$$

Second one most easy is to estimate:
$$\left | (x ^ 2 + 2y) \sin \left(\frac{1}{xy} \right) \right| \leqslant x^2 + 2|y| \to0, \text{ when } (x,y) \to (0,0)$$